# HDD dismounts when reading a specific file

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

For the life of me I can't find the answer on google.

I have damaged files on my additional internal hard drive, when the HDD tries to read them, it dismounts on it's own.

I bought a new hard disk and copied all the files from the old one there, and I get the same problem on the new one, so it's definitely a file issue.

Trying to delete the damaged files with windows explorer causes a dismount and fails.

How do I correct this so that all the files work?

Deleting them is fine, but recovery is preferred.

Comment: Can you read the content of the file if you use some sort of Linux LiveCD/LiveUSB?

Comment: Does it happen with only 1 file / folder? If so, copy all the other files / folders and then see what you can get out of the problem folder.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that trying to read a damaged file would unmount a disk. I suspect you have some other underlying problem causing these symptoms.

Comment: @Darius I haven't tried any linux live usb yet

Comment: @SolarMike it happens to several files in one folder (but I think it's actually more than one folder), not all of them. I already copied all the other files out, but I can't delete this folder

Comment: Back it all up and re-format the disc - personally I would not rely on that folder structure anymore...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, for me knowing what folder it is let's me to use other directories of the drive normally. It actually stops reading from it then dismount the drive !